# How to add an if statement to a php function that returns error when empty

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

This is probably a stupid question but I'm quite new to php so any help would be appreciated. I'm using [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63266/show-a-list-of-recently-viewed-posts-to-a-user/63272) to show members in my wordpress based website the latest posts they've visited. It works fine except when they haven't visited any posts, then it returns an error. (***Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in*** and ***Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in*** ) I know I need to add a if statement to echo "You haven't seen any posts yet" but I'm lost at where to add it. I hope someone can help me out and thanks very much in advance!

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: WPSE_63266_Recently_Viewed
 */
function wpse_63266_update_recently_viewed(){

    /**
     *  If is admin or isn't single, then return.
     *  To get only singular video posts use; if(!is_singular('videos')) return;
     */
    if(is_admin() || !is_single()) return;

    global $post;

    // Get the current post id.
    $current_post_id = get_the_ID();

    if(is_user_logged_in()){

        // Store recently viewed post ids in user meta.
        $recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', true);
        if( '' == $recenty_viewed ){
            $recenty_viewed = array();            
        }

        // Prepend id to the beginning of recently viewed id array.(http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)
        array_unshift($recenty_viewed, $current_post_id);        

        // Keep the recently viewed items at 5. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
        $recenty_viewed = array_slice($recenty_viewed, 0, 10); // Extract a slice of the array

        // Update the user meta with new value.
        update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', $recenty_viewed);

    } else {

    /**
     * For non-logged in users you can use the same procedure as above
     * using get_option() and update_option()
     */

    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse_63266_update_recently_viewed');

function wpse_63266_show_recently_viewed(){
    $recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', true);
$evets=array_unique($recenty_viewed);
    $hadi = get_the_terms( $evets, 'video-genres' ); 
        $hadi2 = get_the_terms( $evets, 'video-type' ); 
            $hadi3 = get_the_terms( $evets, 'video-category' ); 
    
    
    
    foreach($evets as $evet) {
 echo '<div class="soncular"><div class="soncol1"><a href="'.get_permalink($evet).'"><img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($evet, 'progression-studios-video-index').'"</a></div>'; 
echo '<div class="soncol2"><b><strong><a href="'.get_permalink($evet).'">'.get_the_title($evet).'</a></strong></b>';
echo '<br><span>'.$hadi->name.'</span>';
    echo '<br><span>'.$hadi3->name.'</span>';
    echo '<br><span>'.$hadi2->name.'</span></div></div>';
}
    

}
add_action('wpse_63266_recently_viewed', 'wpse_63266_show_recently_viewed');
```

UPDATE:

Following CBroe's advice, I've updated the function as below. Now the empty array shows no error bu the echoed code, but the actual array does not show the last viewed posts. It always turns up empty.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse_63266_update_recently_viewed');

function wpse_63266_show_recently_viewed(){
    if(is_array($recenty_viewed)){
    $recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', true);
$evets=array_unique($recenty_viewed);
    $hadi = get_the_terms( $evets, 'video-genres' ); 
        $hadi2 = get_the_terms( $evets, 'video-type' ); 
            $hadi3 = get_the_terms( $evets, 'video-category' ); 
    
    
    
    foreach($evets as $evet) {
 echo '<div class="soncular"><div class="soncol1"><a href="'.get_permalink($evet).'"><img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($evet, 'progression-studios-video-index').'"</a></div>'; 
echo '<div class="soncol2"><b><strong><a href="'.get_permalink($evet).'">'.get_the_title($evet).'</a></strong></b>';
echo '<br><span>'.$hadi->name.'</span>';
    echo '<br><span>'.$hadi3->name.'</span>';
    echo '<br><span>'.$hadi2->name.'</span></div></div>';
}}
    else {

  echo'hmm';
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `is_array` to check whether you actually got an array, and based on that either proceed with the code that makes the values unique and then loops over and outputs your array data, and output your alternative message otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't know where to add that code and return something else if array is empty. It would be very much appreciated if you could help a bit further.

Comment: Well you’d want to wrap everything from (including) the array_unique (which gave you the error here in the first place), and until after the foreach loop, into an according `if`, and then your message output would go into an `else` block after that.

Comment: I did as you suggested and updated the post. Could you please perhaps check the updated code?

Comment: Now you are trying to check if the variable is an array, before you actually assigned a value to that variable … `$recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(…);` belongs _before_ the if.

Comment: Ah I feel super stupid. I moved the array definition to the upper line and it works just fine now! Thank you VERY MUCH, you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

The `true` value at the end means it will return a single value, not an array

```
$recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', true);
```

See the docs for [get_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)

Change to

```
$recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', false);
```

I think you also then need to call for the terms individually for each recent post

```
function wpse_63266_show_recently_viewed(){
    $recenty_viewed = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', false);
    $evets=array_unique($recenty_viewed);

    foreach($evets as $evet) {
        $hadi = get_the_terms( $evet, 'video-genres' );
        $hadi2 = get_the_terms( $evet, 'video-type' );
        $hadi3 = get_the_terms( $evet, 'video-category' );
        echo '<div class="soncular"><div class="soncol1"><a href="'.get_permalink($evet).'"><img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($evet, 'progression-studios-video-index').'"</a></div>'; 
        echo '<div class="soncol2"><b><strong><a href="'.get_permalink($evet).'">'.get_the_title($evet).'</a></strong></b>';
        echo '<br><span>'.$hadi->name.'</span>';
        echo '<br><span>'.$hadi3->name.'</span>';
        echo '<br><span>'.$hadi2->name.'</span></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the function stops working completely.

Comment: Is there any error output? Could be another bug lower down once you're getting an array back

Comment: Sorry, I changed both parts and it's working now but it still shows the same "array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in" error I've mentioend above.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot to change the `true` value, updated now

Comment: Thank you, now the empty error is gone but the function is not working as it is supposed to do. It only shows the "hello world" post, and not the actual video posts the user has visited. The post_type is "video_skrn", do we need to specify that? It used to work before without adding that. I didnt feel the need to add it as it is actually the only post type users can see.

Comment: I think recently_viewed only works with posts not other post_types, but I may be wrong

Comment: I've fixed it by adding an is_array to the code. Thank you!